How to pass selected values from view to controller using select2 in Yii2
I am using kartik select2 for picking up the numbers.
<?= $form->field($model, 'msn')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'msn-select', // Add an id attribute
        'placeholder' => 'Select meters...',
        'multiple' => true,
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 1,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => Url::to(['taskconfig/list']),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }'),
            'processResults' => new JsExpression('function(data) { 
            return {
                results: $.map(data.results, function(item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.text
                    };
                })
            };
        }'),
        ],
    ],
])->label('Meters'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::a('Download Excel', ['download'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','id' => 'download-btn']) ?>
</div>

Controller
public function actionDownload()
{

    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    die(0);
}

When I click on Download Excel button I am getting NULL or array(0) { } in my controller. How can I pass the selected values? They could be more than one
Updated Code
Form
<div class="task-config-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'task','method'=>'post']); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'msn')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'msn-select', // Add an id attribute
        'placeholder' => 'Select meters...',
        'multiple' => true,
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 1,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => Url::to(['taskconfig/list']),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }'),
            'processResults' => new JsExpression('function(data) { 
            return {
                results: $.map(data.results, function(item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.text
                    };
                })
            };
        }'),
        ],
    ],
])->label('Meters'); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Download Excel', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'download-btn', 'name' => 'download']) ?>

</div>



<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

Controller
public function actionDownload()
{

    $postData = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $msnArray = $postData['TaskConfig']['msn'];
    // Remove any empty values from the array
    $msnArrayFilter = array_filter($msnArray);

    if (empty($msnArrayFilter)) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'No meters selected.');
        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => TaskConfig::find()->select(['msn', 'ak', 'ek', 'utility'])->where(['msn' => $msnArrayFilter]),
        'pagination' => false,
    ]);

    $models = $dataProvider->getModels();

    // Create Excel file
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    // Set headers
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Msn');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Ak');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Ek');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Utility');

    // Fill data
    $row = 2;
    foreach ($msnArray as $msn)
    {
        // Assuming TaskConfig::find() returns models with the same attributes as the Excel columns
        $model = TaskConfig::find()->where(['msn' => $msn])->one();
        if ($model !== null) {
            $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, $model->msn);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $model->ak);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $row, $model->ek);
            $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $row, $model->utility);
            $row++;
        }
    }

    // Save the Excel file content to a temporary file
    $microseconds = microtime(true); // Get current timestamp with microseconds
    $microseconds = str_replace('.', '', $microseconds); // Remove the dot from microseconds
    $filename = 'task_config_' . date('YmdHis') . '_' . $microseconds . '.xlsx';
    try {
        // Save Excel file to temporary location
        $tempFilePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . $filename;
        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->save($tempFilePath);

        // Send the file content to the user for download
        Yii::$app->response->sendFile($tempFilePath, $filename)->send();
        return;
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        // Handle any exceptions
        Yii::error('Error generating Excel file: ' . $e->getMessage());
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'An error occurred while generating the Excel file.');
        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
    }

}

Any help would be highly appreciated

Download is a normal link.. Instead of creating a normal link.... you can create it as Submit Form Button ,, you will get value through $_POST

There's nothing linking your download anchor tag to the form itself. You'll need to do the above suggestion or you can write some JS to prevent default, collect the data and send an ajax request to the controller. But converting to a submit button is easier.

@DoubleH I have tried with <div class="form-group">         <?= Html::submitButton('Download Excel', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'download-btn', 'name' => 'download']) ?>     </div> but still the form is not submitting to download action controller

@Moeez Show me you complete form code

Maybe csrf protection isn't implemented properly. This would prevent post requests. Do you have csrf protection enabled and do you have a <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?> in the <head> section in your layout?
